# How to implement asynchronous calls for payment in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, routes, stripe-payments

Hopefully someone can provide me some insight as there are a few things I am unsure about here as I am a newer developer.

So I have been working on implementing a custom stripe checkout for the past few days and I think what I have to do here is perform an asynchronous action from my rails view for my checkout to my server to confirm if a payment is valid.

At stripes website I have found the solution I want to implement, but Im not crystal clear on what they mean, I have an idea what they are referring to and think I can do it, but Im honestly not sure where I put my server side code in rails to handle this async call. Does it go in my controller? inside a method in my controller? Do I make another file somewhere?

```
function stripePaymentMethodHandler(result) {
  if (result.error) {
    // Show error in payment form
  } else {
    // Otherwise send paymentMethod.id to your server (see Step 4)
    fetch('/pay', { // I am not sure about this part. They say to make an endpoint on my server to handle this, does this mean I make a route only for this action in my routes? Then this action gets performed via that route?
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        payment_method_id: result.paymentMethod.id,
      })
    }).then(function(result) {
      // Handle server response (see Step 4)
      result.json().then(function(json) {
        handleServerResponse(json);
      })
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the corresponding server side code I need to implement, and, I understand the code itself, Im just not sure where I put this honestly. In my controller? In my create action?

```
post '/pay' do
  data = JSON.parse(request.body.read.to_s)

  begin
    if data['payment_method_id']
      # Create the PaymentIntent
      intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create(
        payment_method: data['payment_method_id'],
        amount: 1099,
        currency: 'usd',
        confirmation_method: 'manual',
        confirm: true,
      )
    elsif data['payment_intent_id']
      intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.confirm(data['payment_intent_id'])
    end
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    # Display error on client
    return [200, { error: e.message }.to_json]
  end

  return generate_response(intent)
end

def generate_response(intent)
  # Note that if your API version is before 2019-02-11, 'requires_action'
  # appears as 'requires_source_action'.
  if intent.status == 'requires_action' &&
      intent.next_action.type == 'use_stripe_sdk'
    # Tell the client to handle the action
    [
      200,
      {
        requires_action: true,
        payment_intent_client_secret: intent.client_secret
      }.to_json
    ]
  elsif intent.status == 'succeeded'
    # The payment didn’t need any additional actions and is completed!
    # Handle post-payment fulfillment
    [200, { success: true }.to_json]
  else
    # Invalid status
    return [500, { error: 'Invalid PaymentIntent status' }.to_json]
  end
end
```

I understand what this is all doing, the most confusing part for me is the "/pay" route the are referencing here. Can I perform these requests to a url my site already has? For example '/orders/new' ? Or do i need to make a new route called, say, '/pay' as in there example and this route will only be used for this call? If so, how do I define this in my routes? resources :pay, or something? What resources would this route have? Is it just a placeholder where information gets stored?

Any help is appreciated! Ive been trying to find some explicit examples on the web using RoR and   maybe im googling the wrong thing, because I cant find too much.

Comment: This looks like a Sinatra example. Could you point me to the part of the docs where you took this from? Then I might be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples are using Sinatra as the web framework, so the actual routing will look a little different with Rails. Basically anywhere you see a route defined in the examples with `get` or `post` you'll want to create a route in your routes.rb file and add a controller action that maps to that route and use the logic from the example. You can translate from `data = JSON.parse(request.body.read.to_s)` to `params` in a fairly expected way with the following example below.

In Rails, you would either use an existing route, or define a new one in your routes.rb file:

```
# routes.rb
resources :orders, only: [:create]
```

Then in the JavaScript, you can update the path used in the fetch call to map to your own route defined in Rails. So that could be:

```
fetch('/orders', // ...
```

Then the logic to handle the request would live inside of your OrdersController. In this case, you'd likely make a `create` action to handle this POST request:

```
# OrdersController
def create
  begin
    if params[:payment_method_id]
      # Create the PaymentIntent
      intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create(
        payment_method: params[:payment_method_id],
        amount: 1099,
        currency: 'usd',
        confirmation_method: 'manual',
        confirm: true,
      )
    elsif params[:payment_intent_id]
      intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.confirm(params[:payment_intent_id])
    end
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    # Display error on client
    render json: { error: e.message }
  end

  return generate_response(intent)
end 

def generate_response(intent)
  # Note that if your API version is before 2019-02-11, 'requires_action'
  # appears as 'requires_source_action'.
  if intent.status == 'requires_action' &&
      intent.next_action.type == 'use_stripe_sdk'
    # Tell the client to handle the action
    render json: {
      requires_action: true,
      payment_intent_client_secret: intent.client_secret
    }
  elsif intent.status == 'succeeded'
    # The payment didn’t need any additional actions and is completed!
    # Handle post-payment fulfillment
    render json: { success: true }
  else
    # Invalid status
    render json: { error: 'Invalid PaymentIntent status' }, 500, .to_json]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very clear and just what I was looking for! I will look into Sinatra also to learn something new!

Answer (score 1):

You'll indeed need to put the logic in a controller, let's call it Payments

**1. Generate the controller**

```
$> rails g controller Payments
```

**2. Define the create method**

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        begin
          if payment_params[:payment_method_id]
            # Create the PaymentIntent
            intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create(
              payment_method: payment_params[:payment_method_id],
              amount: 1099,
              currency: 'usd',
              confirmation_method: 'manual',
              confirm: true,
            )
          elsif payment_params[:payment_intent_id]
            intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.confirm(payment_params[:payment_intent_id])
          end
        rescue Stripe::CardError => e
          # Display error on client
          render json:  { status: :unprocessable_entity, message: e.message }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def payment_params
    params.permit(:payment_method_id, :payment_intent_id)
  end

  def generate_response(intent)
    # Note that if your API version is before 2019-02-11, 'requires_action'
    # appears as 'requires_source_action'.
    if intent.status == 'requires_action' &&
        intent.next_action.type == 'use_stripe_sdk'
      # Tell the client to handle the action
      render json: {
        status: 200,
        requires_action: true,
        payment_intent_client_secret: intent.client_secret
      }
    elsif intent.status == 'succeeded'
      # The payment didn’t need any additional actions and is completed!
      # Handle post-payment fulfillment
      render json: { status: 200 }
    else
      # Invalid status
      render json: { status: 500, message: 'Invalid PaymentIntent status' }
    end
  end
end
```

**3. Define the route**

routes.rb

```
resources :payments, only: %i[create]
```

**4. Replace the route in your code**

```
fetch('/payments.json' ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!